# How can I check the database of a table?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table name SOME_TABLE but I don't know the databse it belongs to.
How do I check it?
I suppose, it's impossible to do it from Hive level, cause you need to select database first...

Pawel

Answer (score 0):

Query the metastore directly

#### Demo

**Hive**

```
create table SOME_TABLE (i int);
```

**Metastore (MySQL)**

```
use metastore;


select  d.name
        
from            TBLS                as t

        join    DBS                 as d
        
        on      d.DB_ID =
                t.DB_ID

where   t.TBL_NAME   = 'some_table'
;
```

---

```
+----------+
|   name   |
+----------+
| local_db |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Hive command `SHOW DATABASES;` to list all databases and then use the `SHOW TABLES IN database_name LIKE 'table_name';` command to to see if the table exist in the database.